# interpretation for =INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$1214,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$1214=B2)*(Sheet2!$F$2:$F$1214=O2),0))

Tags: excel

Hi can anyone please to interpreate the following

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$1214,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$1214=B2)*(Sheet2!$F$2:$F$1214=O2),0))
```

I have tried to understand this by looking at Index with Match functions.

```
Match(1,-------
```

Why is that first parameter 1 for Match() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is with the MATCH function so I will just explain on this.
Let's first assume we have some data in the excel as below.

> $A$1 = 2; $A$2 = 7
>
> $B$1:$B$5 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>
> $C$1:$C$5 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 0}

Now, we try to solve the equation below:

> $B$1:$B$5 = $A$1
>
> $C$1:$C$5 = $A$2

What excel does is it takes the value of $A$1 and compare it against $B$1, $B$2, and so on. The result will return as follow:

> "$B$1:$B$5 = $A$1" = {FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE}
>
> "$C$1:$C$5 = $A$2" = {FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE}

Then we do this..

> ($B$1:$B$5 = $A$1) * ($C$1:$C$5 = $A$2)

It will take 1 data from the same position in each of the result we got above, multiply it and return the result.

> "{FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE} * {FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE}"
>
> = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}

So the MATCH function will have the input as follow..

> MATCH(1, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 0)

What this equation means is it will attempt to look for value "1" in the array, and return the position of the **FIRST** value that matched.

In our case, it will return 2.

Then this "2" is passed as row_num into INDEX function..

You can explain the rest by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the formula starting at the components of the inner `MATCH`. For this I assume that this is an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx).

As an array formula, `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$1214=B2` gives a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` depending on whether the values in `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$1214` equal `B2`. Similarly, `Sheet2!$F$2:$F$1214=O2` gives a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` depending on whether the values in `Sheet2!$F$2:$F$1214` equal `O2`.

Now, `(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$1214=B2)*(Sheet2!$F$2:$F$1214=O2)` multiplies two vectors of `TRUE` and `FALSE` row by row. Since `TRUE*TRUE=1`, but `FALSE*TRUE=TRUE*FALSE=FALSE*FALSE=0`, this gives a vector of `1` and `0` depending of whetter `B2` equals `Sheet2!$A$r` and `O2` equals `Sheet2!$F$r` *for the same row* `r`.

The `MATCH(1, ...)` then finds the first row `r` on `Sheet2` where both `B2` equals `Sheet2!$A$r` and `O2` equals `Sheet2!$F$r` *for the same row* `r`.

Finally, the `INDEX` gives you the value in `Sheet2!$B$2:$B$1214` for this row `r`.